# left shift operator null-space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the left shift operator over the infinite complex vector field. Show that 
$\operatorname{null}(S−I)^3=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1,\dots),(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots),(0,1,4,9,16,25,\dots)\}$.

To start I found that $(S−I)^3$ is defined by 
$(S−I)^3(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,\dots)=(x_1−3x_2+3x_3−x_4,x_2−3x_3+3x_4−x_5,\dots)$, which defines the recursive relationship $x_i+3=x_i−3x_i+1+3x_i+2$ which equals zero if in the null. Each of the three vectors satisfy the above equation, but how do I prove that they span? I.e. that nothing else belongs in the null.

Answer (score 2):

For brevity, let's write $T := S- I$. Note that the kernel of $T^2$ has$\def\ran{\mathop{\rm ran}}$ 
$$ \ker (T^2) = \ker T + \ker T|_{\ran T} $$
As $\ker T|_{\ran T} = \ker T \cap \ran T \subseteq \ker T$, we conclude that 
$$ \dim \ker T^2 \le \dim \ker T + \dim (\ker T \cap \ran T) \le 2 \dim \ker T$$
Along the same lines, 
$$ \dim \ker T^3 \le \dim \ker T^2 +\dim \ker T \le 3 \dim \ker T $$
As $x \in \ker T = \ker (S - I)$ iff $x_{i+1} = x_i$ for all $i$, we conclude that $\ker (S -I) = {\rm span}\{(1,1, \ldots)\}$ - this recursion has only the constants as solutions. This gives $\dim\ker T = 1$, hence
$$ \dim \ker T^3 \le 3 $$
As you have found three independent elements of the at most three-dimensional space $\dim \ker T^3$, they must be spanning.